# In Python, why does console output occasionally pause until ctrl-c is pressed, and how can I stop this?

Tags: python

This issue seems to crop up once every week or so while doing Python development. Whether in Bash on Linux or cmd.exe or Powershell, Python scripts will sometimes pause their output, leading one to believe they may have locked up. Upon having ctrl-c pressed, the console output will resume, and it will be apparent that the script has been executing in the background. As if scroll lock had been pressed or something.

The program doesn't matter and it can only be reproduced over time. You could run the following snip:

```
import time

i = 0
while True:
    print i
    i++
    time.sleep(1)
```

And in the next week or so, the console will pause, even though i is still increasing every second in the background.

This isn't just poor design on my end - I had this happen to a Celery process more than once & a Django test server, along with my own programs. Normally I would just consider it a 'nuisance' but ctrl-c can also accidentally terminate the program if it's actually, really busy.

This behavior has also existed for my co-workers, but nobody seems to know what to do about it.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you specify which version of python you are using?

Comment: I don't think `i++` is valid in any Python version, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I have experienced this in powershell.  If I click in the text area it pauses output and if I hit enter it continues.  Very annoying.

Comment: _"Upon having ctrl-c pressed, the console output will __resume__"_?! Code that doesn't catch a KeyboardInterrupt will _resume_? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Have you accidentally pressed Ctrl-S ? This will freeze console output.

Comment: ctrl+c is the KeyboardInterrupt. It should stop the code from executing. This leads me to believe that some other code or script that you have on your machine starts and is blocking the current one from executing. The ctrl+c might be stopping that and allowing the original code to continue.

Comment: Have the same experience with a python script started under Windows (tested in 7 and 10). I have to hit enter to proceed at some random point. (Regarding some of the comments: the ctrl+c is not really the point of the question)

Comment: Possible answer, at least for Windows: https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why

Answer (score 0):

Prehaps you pressed outside the window or pressed ctrl-S (which pauses consle output)